# Google SEO friendly URLs using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, seo, mybb

I run a forum and I am trying to modify the .htaccess so that we can have more friendly URLs.

This is my .htaccess. We are using an SSL certificate on the site and want to force the HTTPS :)

```
RewriteEngine On
# Some hosts require RewriteBase to make RewriteRules work.
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^&]*)&(.*)$ https://example.com/$1?$2 [L,QSA,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule !/status https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php

# Google SEO workaround for search.php highlights:
# Make this rule the first rewrite rule in your .htaccess!
RewriteRule ^([^&]*)&(.*)$ https://example.com/$1?$2 [L,QSA,R=301]

# Google SEO 404:
ErrorDocument 404 /misc.php?google_seo_error=404

# Google SEO Sitemap:
RewriteRule ^sitemap\-([^./]+)\.xml$ misc.php?google_seo_sitemap=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# Google SEO URL Forums:
RewriteRule ^Forum\-([^./]+)$ forumdisplay.php?google_seo_forum=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# Google SEO URL Threads:
RewriteRule ^Thread\-([^./]+)$ showthread.php?google_seo_thread=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# Google SEO URL Announcements:
RewriteRule ^Announcement\-([^./]+)$ announcements.php?google_seo_announcement=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# Google SEO URL Users:
RewriteRule ^User\-([^./]+)$ member.php?action=profile&google_seo_user=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# Google SEO URL Calendars:
RewriteRule ^Calendar\-([^./]+)$ calendar.php?google_seo_calendar=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# Google SEO URL Events:
RewriteRule ^Event\-([^./]+)$ calendar.php?action=event&google_seo_event=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: What problem are you facing with this?

Answer (score 1):

These are the three lines I use to achieve HTTPS.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I also noticed you don't have

```
IndexIgnore *
```

In there, which is really nice because it stops people from being able to view your web directory as an index (can see names of your files and folder directories)